# How to select and extract data from a form that is submitted with AJAX which is among other forms with the same class name?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have written a code (which is a working progress I must confess) that wraps a form individually with each cell in a table. The form will be submitted by pressing `Enter` Thus each cell in a table will be a mini form and the number of cells may vary, depending on database variables.

Long story short, this is the section of code that creates the form:

```
$output .= '
                    <td><form class="submit_results" onsubmit="return submit_results();"><input class="hidden" name="result_id" value="'.$result_id.'"><input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row2.'"><input class="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'"><input class="hidden" name="sample_id" value="'.$sam_id.'"><input name="result" placeholder="'.$input4['m_analysis'].'" value="'.$input5['result'].'"><input class="hidden" type="submit"></form></td>';
```

Now I want to be able to submit the form, that is to say the cell that the user enters a value into the cell, individually, using AJAX as follows:

```
    function submit_results() {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../server/insert_tests.php?submit_results",
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(message){
        $('#success').html(message).fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

        var display_analyses = $("#order_id").val();
        var url4 = "../server/insert_tests.php?display_full_results=";

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
          url: url4 + display_analyses,             
          success: function(data) {
            $("#full_table_results").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
     event.preventDefault();
   }
```

However, the `data: $('form').serialize(),` part of the code only fetches data from the last `form`. I know why this is happening, probably due to the fact that the code cannot distinguish between the forms and which one was submitted. Using classes does not work either and id's can't be used if the form will be generated in multiple repititions. I have tried:

`$(this).closest('form').serialize(),`

But no luck. Can someone please provide solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an inline event handler, use jQuery's event handling syntax.

Remove

```
onsubmit="return submit_results();
```

and replace the "submit_results()" function with an event handler which attaches to all forms with the same class:

```
$(".submit_results").submit(function(event) { ... });
```

Then within that, when the handler executes, the form which was actually submitted will be represented by `this`. So you can use `$(this).serialize()` to capture the data from the specific form submitted.

Complete code:

PHP:

```
$output .= '<td><form class="submit_results"><input class="hidden" name="result_id" value="'.$result_id.'"><input class="hidden" name="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row2.'"><input class="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'"><input class="hidden" name="sample_id" value="'.$sam_id.'"><input name="result" placeholder="'.$input4['m_analysis'].'" value="'.$input5['result'].'"><input class="hidden" type="submit"></form></td>';
```

JS (make sure this is within a `$(document).ready() { ... })` block so it doesn't try to bind the events before the elements have been rendered):

```
$(".submit_results").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../server/insert_tests.php?submit_results",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(message){
        $('#success').html(message).fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

        var display_analyses = $("#order_id").val();
        var url4 = "../server/insert_tests.php?display_full_results=";

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
          url: url4 + display_analyses,             
          success: function(data) {
            $("#full_table_results").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

N.B. As well as making your desired functionality work more easily, using unobtrusive event handlers (instead of inline ones) is generally considered best practice in modern web development, as it creates a better separation of code from presentation, and also makes the code clearer and more traceable (you don't have to hunt around in the HTML for dozens of event handlers, you can see it all in one place in the JS instead), which should help with debugging and ongoing maintenance.

Comment: Great answer! It all makes sense, except when I submit the form, the page redirects and puts the data information in the url?

Comment: It shouldn't be doing, due to the event.preventDefault. the only thing I can think is that the event isn't binding and therefore it's doing a regular form submit instead. Did you make sure the code was within a document.ready block as I mentioned? Either that or make sure the script block comes after the table in your page. I assume you're not loading the table HTML via Ajax or anything like that?

Comment: Yes I am loading the table using AJAX, I have placed the submit function in the success section of the table load ajax. Submission works the first time but redirects the second time.

Comment: I had to reset the form after each submission to get it to work like this: `var form = $('.submit_results').reset();
              return false;`. That did it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The ajax will be the reason then. The events do not bind properly because you replace the HTML each time and the event is only bound to the original version (if any). Replace `$(".submit_results").submit(function(event) {` with `$(document).on("submit", "".submit_results"", function(event) {`. Then read the section called "Direct and delegated" events in the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ to understand why that works better.